# Two State Toggle Button with slideToggle JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with showing two different states for the toggle button. When I do click the button, it displays the hidden h1 text. But, it doesn't remove the h1 text after the slideToggle() method retracts. To be 100% clear: I need the calendar container to minimize when I click the toggle button. And I need the the hidden message to show in it's place? Vice versa.

```js
    
        $(document).on('turbolinks:load', function () {
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("div#hide-calendar").slideToggle("slow", "linear", function(){
                  $("div#calendar-minimized-panel-msg").show();
                });
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="close-calendar-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="hide-calendar">Minimize Calendar</button>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-title">
        <h4>Appointment Calendar</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="calendar-container" id="hide-calendar">
        <%= month_calendar appointments: @appointments do |date, appointments| %>
            <%= date %>
            <% appointments.each do |appointment| %>
                <div>
                  <%= appointment.name %>
                </div>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <div id="calendar-minimized-panel-msg" style= "display: none;">
        <h3>Maximize Calendar Message</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the element state is visible or hidden and update the message element state based on that. You can use [`toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/) method to toggle the state and use [`is()`](https://api.jquery.com/is/) and [`:hidden`](https://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) to get the boolean value of based on main element state.

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $("div#hide-calendar").slideToggle("slow", "linear", function() {
    $("div#calendar-minimized-panel-msg").toggle($(this).is(':hidden'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="close-calendar-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" id="hide-calendar">Minimize Calendar</button>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar-title">
    <h4>Appointment Calendar</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="calendar-container" id="hide-calendar">
    <div>
      fdf
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="calendar-minimized-panel-msg" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Maximize Calendar Message</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div#hide-calendar").slideToggle("slow", "linear", function() {
      $("div#calendar-minimized-panel-msg").toggle($(this).is(':hidden'));
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Is there is a way to change the text in the button from minimize to maximize for the second state?

Comment: @valcod3r :  add `$(this).text($("div#hide-calendar").is(':visible')?'Maximize Calendar':'Minimize Calendar');`

Comment: @valcod3r : update the text, order and place where you want